# php insert string into html after 500 words? include html tags

Tags: php, html, regex, insert

How to insert some string into html after 500 words? (do not break html tags)

```
function insert_string($text,$length,$insert) {
    preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>([^<]*)/',$text,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($m as $i=>$o){
        if($o[0][1]-$i>=$length)
        break;
        $t=substr(strtok($o[0][0]," \t\n\r\0\x0B>"),1);
        // ... can not think how to write continue.
    }
    //...
    return $output;
}


echo insert_string($text,'500','<strong> related tags </stong>');
```

It should be regexp each html tags into loop, remember a certain position and strlen() the text length , then determined where to insert some sting. But i can not think how to write continue. needs for help. thanks.

Comment: what do you consider a word? anything separated with a space?

Comment: @Fede, simple code explain, like this `echo insert_string('<div id="mw-content-text"><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>dolor sit</p><p>amet</p></div>',10,"<stong> related news </stong>");` => `<div id="mw-content-text"><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>dolor <stong> related news </stong> sit</p><p>amet</p></div>`, it should be not break html tag and should consider not break a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I had a more or less similar issue once. I modified my coding so it (hopefully) solves your problem.
It is not perfect but it worked for me:

```
//start 'config
$string = '<div id="mw-content-text"><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p><b>dolor</b> sit</p><p>amet</p></div>';
$words = array();
$insert_after_x_words = 3;
$insert_string = '<br>INSERT YOUR STUFF HERE<br>';
//end 'config'

$needle = '<';
$positions_tagopen = array();
$lastPos = 0;
while (($lastPos = strpos($string, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
  array_push($positions_tagopen, $lastPos);
  $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}

$needle = '>';
$positions_tagclose = array();
$lastPos = 0;
while (($lastPos = strpos($string, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
  array_push($positions_tagclose, $lastPos);
  $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}


$current_pos = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($positions_tagopen); $i++)
{
  $current_substring = substr($string,$current_pos,$positions_tagopen[$i]-$current_pos);
  $tmp = explode(" ",$current_substring);
  for($i2 = 0; $i2 < count($tmp); $i2++)
  {
    if(strlen($tmp[$i2])>0)
    {
      if($i2+1<count($tmp))
      {
        $tmp[$i2] = $tmp[$i2]." ";
      }
      array_push($words, $tmp[$i2]);                
    }
  }

  array_push($words, html_escape(substr($string,$positions_tagopen[$i], $positions_tagclose[$i]-$positions_tagopen[$i]).'>'));
  $current_pos = $positions_tagclose[$i]+1;
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++)
{
  if(($i)%$insert_after_x_words == 0 && $i > 0)
  {
    echo $insert_string;
  }
  echo $words[$i];
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function html_escape().

Comment: a HTML-Tag is considered 'a word'.

Comment: You use an old version of PHP. However this is only used for debugging and you can remove it. Because if your string contains something like a <p> (or other HTML tags) it will create a new paragraph in the debugging output (the result will still be correct)

Comment: where is the manual of html_escape()? I can not find it in php.net

Comment: You can also use `htmlentities()` or similar functions. As I said i only used it for escaping the html-tags so the debugging(!) output is readable when displayed in your web browser. I do not know why this function is available in my PHP distribution (it is a regular XAMPP-Server)

Comment: `html_escape` doesn't exist in PHP, it's a CodeIgniter/omeka function.

Comment: Oh indeed. Wrote it in a CI environment. However this part is not crucial for the actual functionality. Please upvote if it worked for you Giberno or tell us in case it did not.